If $x, y, z$ are real numbers with $xy+yz+zx\geq0,$ then $\left(x^5 + y^5 + z^5\right)^2 \geq3xyz\left(x^7 +y^7 + z^7\right).$
Question: If $x, y, z$ are real numbers with $xy+yz+zx\geq0,$ then
$$\left(x^5 + y^5 + z^5\right)^2 \geq3xyz\left(x^7 +y^7 + z^7\right).$$

Attempt:
Let's consider the expression $$\left(x^5 + y^5 + z^5\right)^2 \geq 3xyz\left(x^7 +y^7 + z^7\right)$$ and try to manipulate it.
We know that $xy + yz + zx \geq 0,$ which implies that the terms involving $x$, $y$, and $z$ are non-negative.
First we expand the left side of the inequality:
$$\left(x^5 + y^5 + z^5\right)^2 = x^{10} + y^{10} + z^{10} + 2(x^5y^5 + y^5z^5 + z^5x^5).$$
Now we aim to manipulate the right side:
$$3xyz\left(x^7 +y^7 + z^7\right) = 3xyz(x^7 + y^7 + z^7).$$
Here, we note that the terms $x^7$, $y^7$, and $z^7$ have greater powers compared to the terms $x^5$, $y^5$, and $z^5$ on the left side. Thus, we can't directly compare them.
We need to establish a connection between the two sides. However, the given condition $xy + yz + zx \geq 0$ doesn't directly help us in this context.

If $x,y,z\ge 0$, it is a problem of AMM. Otherwise, WLOG, assume that $x, y \le 0$ and $z=1$. Then some BW (Buffalo Way) -like approach should work. But it is not nice.

@RiverLi can you elaborate your proof?

It is not nice. Perhaps in some days.

@RiverLi any progress?

I will post something soon.

As @Amir's nice answer shows, the non-trivial part of your question is just the AMM problem 11543. Surely, it is expected to see a nice proof (in Math Olympiad style sense, e.g. without Lagrange Multipliers/KKT) for AMM 11543.

As @Amir's nice answer pointed out,
the difficult case is $x, y, z > 0$ which is just AMM, 2010, no. 10, Problem 11543.
Here we give a proof of AMM Problem 11543
using the pqr method.
WLOG, assume that $xy + yz + zx = 3$.
Let $p = x + y + z, q = xy + yz + zx = 3, r = xyz$.
Using $p^2 \ge 3q$, we have $p\ge 3$.
The desired inequality is written as
\begin{align*}
 f(r) &:= -21\,p{r}^{3}+ \left( 4\,{p}^{4}+39\,{p}^{2}+36 \right) {r}^{2} + 
 \left( 7\,{p}^{7}-117\,{p}^{5}+522\,{p}^{3}-783\,p \right) r\\
 &\qquad +{p}^{10}
 -30\,{p}^{8}+315\,{p}^{6}-1350\,{p}^{4}+2025\,{p}^{2} \ge 0.\tag{1}
\end{align*}
We have
$$0 \le (x - y)^2(y-z)^2(z-x)^2 = -4\,{p}^{3}r+{p}^{2}{q}^{2}+18\,pqr-4\,{q}^{3}-27\,{r}^{2}$$
which results in
$$g(r) := -27\,{r}^{2}+ \left( -4\,{p}^{3}+54\,p \right) r+9\,{p}^{2}-108 \ge 0.\tag{2}$$
From (1) and (2), it suffices to prove that
$$9 f(r) - 7pr g(r) \ge 0,$$
or
\begin{align*}
 h(r) &:=  \left( 64\,{p}^{4}-27\,{p}^{2}+324 \right) {r}^{2}+ \left( 63\,{p}^{7
 }-1053\,{p}^{5}+4635\,{p}^{3}-6291\,p \right) r\\
&\qquad + 9p^2(p^4-15p^2+45)^2 \ge 0. \tag{3}
\end{align*}
From (2), we have
$$r \le r_2 := -\frac{2}{27}p^3 + p + \frac{2}{27}\sqrt{(p^2 - 9)^3}. \tag{4}$$
From (3) and (4), it suffices to prove that
$h(r) \ge 0$ for all $r\in [0, r_2]$.
(i) If $p \ge 59/18$, we have $63\,{p}^{7
}-1053\,{p}^{5}+4635\,{p}^{3}-6291\,p > 0$, and thus $h(r) \ge 0$
for all $r \ge 0$.
(ii) If $3 \le p \le 61/20$, we have
\begin{align*}
 h'(r) &= 2\left( 64\,{p}^{4}-27\,{p}^{2}+324 \right) r + \left( 63\,{p}^{7
 }-1053\,{p}^{5}+4635\,{p}^{3}-6291\,p \right) \\
 &\le 2\left( 64\,{p}^{4}-27\,{p}^{2}+324 \right) r_2 + \left( 63\,{p}^{7
 }-1053\,{p}^{5}+4635\,{p}^{3}-6291\,p \right)\\
& < 0.
\end{align*}
Thus, $h(r) \ge h(r_2) \ge 0$.
(iii) If $61/20 < p < 59/18$, it suffices to prove that
\begin{align*}
 &4 \times \left( 64\,{p}^{4}-27\,{p}^{2}+324 \right) \times 9p^2(p^4-15p^2+45)^2 \\
 \ge{}& \left( 63\,{p}^{7
 }-1053\,{p}^{5}+4635\,{p}^{3}-6291\,p \right)^2
\end{align*}
which is true.
We are done.

As stated by River in a comment, for $x,y,z>0$ there is a proof for the inequality (see solution of AMM Problem 11543 in page 251 of this pdf), and the remaining case reduces to check the inequality for $z=1, x,y<0$, i.e, if $xy+x+y>0$, then
$$\left(1+x^5 + y^5\right)^2 \geq3xy\left(1+x^7 +y^7 \right).$$
Let us set $a=-x> 0$ and $b=-y> 0$. Then, we need to show for $ab\ge a+b, a,b > 0$:
$$\left(1-a^5 - a^5\right)^2 \geq3ab\left(1-a^7 -a^7 \right).$$
For $1 \le a^7 +a^7$, the above holds. For $a^7 +a^7 < 1$, we have $0<a,b<1$, but the initial condition $ab\ge a+b \Leftrightarrow 1\ge \frac 1 a +\frac 1 b$ cannot hold, and we are done.

Nice. In my opinion, I did not see a nice proof for $x, y, z > 0$. Hope to see nice proof for $x, y, z > 0$.

By the way, in your answer, alternatively, we can say $ab \ge a + b$ implies $a\ge 1, b \ge 1$.

Thank you River! You are always supportive.
